# General formula for all possible propositions in two variables?

Tags: logic

Given p and q, where p and q have either the value True or False, a function f returns either True or False. One example:

```
p     q     f
True  True  True
True  False True
False True  False
False False True
```

Here f could be ${\lnot p \land q}$. There are ${2^4}$ possible outcomes for two variables, meaning there are at least ${2^4}$ unique functions. Is there a general way to figure out all possible functions?

I can only think of listing all possibilities, and thinking of a function that matches that combination. But this way doesn't scale, if you start thinking about functions of $3,4,5,...$ variables.

Edit:
For context this question comes from the book, The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming [[link]](https://fldit-www.cs.uni-dortmund.de/~peter/PS07/HR.pdf), page 60 of the pdf file, Exercise 2.21.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is .... Are you looking for a formula that matches any given possible function? Also, an expression that matches your truth-table would be $\neg (\neg p \land q)$, rather than $\neg p \land q$

Comment: "Figure out all possible functions" (presumably you would mean to enumerate them) and "Figure out the number of all possible functions" is two different questions.  Which one are you wanting?

Comment: @Bram28 - Hi, thanks for the correction. I should have paid more attention.

Comment: @maou No problem .... but what exactly is your question?  I am not clear on that.

Comment: @DanielV - Hi, yes, I suppose I should have said 'enumerate'. There are 16 functions, at the very least (many more that are considered logically equivalent), when you have two boolean variables. I was trying to think of a way to enumerate them all. I realise the simplest solution, is as Bram28 mentions, just to state the preconditions and outcome. I was wondering if there was another less verbose/simpler way to do the same thing.

Comment: @Bram28 - For context this question comes from the book, The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming [https://fldit-www.cs.uni-dortmund.de/~peter/PS07/HR.pdf], page 60 of the pdf file, Exercise 2.21 (I guess parts 4 and 5)

Comment: @maou OK, thanks.  Then I guessed correctly, and my answer below is an answer to those questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your question is ... but if you are looking for a way to match any given truth-function using some formula:

Here is a method that always works, for any function, using any number of variables.

Let's take your truth-table:

```
p     q     f
True  True  True
True  False True
False True  False
False False True
```

For every row where the function comes out True, generate a term that is the conjunction of literals corresponding to that row. That is, the function is True in the first row, and that's where both $p$ and $q$ are True, so the first row gives us term $p \land q$.  The second row gives you $p \land \neg q$, and the fourth corresponds to $\neg p \land \neg q$.

Then put all these terms into one big disjunction, so you get:

$(p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg q)$

If you were to put this statement on a truth-table, you'll find that it captures exactly your function $f$.  I hope you see how you can use this method no matter how many $True$'s you have in the truth-table, and no matter how many variables are involved.

Oh: one special case: what if there are no True's in the function? Well, then the function is a contradiction, so you can just use something like $p \land \neg p$

Just to give an example for 3 variables:

```
p     q     r     f
True  True  True  True
True  True  False False
True  False True  True
True  False False False
False True  True  False
False True  False False
False False True  False
False False False True
```

Now you get: $(p \land q \land r) \lor (p \land \neg q \land r) \lor (\neg p \land \neg q \land \neg r)$

Comment: I have to ask is this the only way?

Comment: No. You can also focus on the $False$'s and generate a formula for that. But you would need to negate that whole thing.

Comment: Right, I suppose, that's different, yet the same in another way. The only other approach I've thought of is using a programming language that supports (or can be made to support) algebraic manipulation and using the logical equivalencies (e.g. De Morgan's law) to come up with other logically equivalent but different propositions. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

$$ f_A(p_0,\ldots p_{n-1}) =
\lfloor A/2^b \rfloor \bmod 2
\quad\text{where }
b = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i p_i $$

where $A\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,2^{2^n}-1\}$ is an index of the function and truth values are represented by $0$ and $1$.

How this works is that $A$ is the final column of the truth table, interpreted as a binary number. The computation of $b$ gives which *row* of the truth table we're in, and $\lfloor A/2^b\rfloor \bmod 2$ then picks out that bit from $A$.

(In a curly-bracket programming language you would write `(A>>b)&1`).

---

In practice, doing this as *arithmetic* does not really scale to more than 6 variables. In order to represent *arbitrary* propositional functions, you would need a different way to represent a bit vector with more than $2^n$ bits. However, in many practical applications, the functions you actually want to represent are not completely random and can be more compactly represented in other ways -- look into [binary decision diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram), for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It took me a while to understand this (I come from programming, and mathematical notation takes me a bit of effort). I tried a few examples and started to understand what you mean. I think its a way to encode a truth table for a function, and perhaps this can represent a propositional function. The question I was after, was given the final column in a truth table (A in you answer, I think) how to generate a function that produces it? I didn't fully understand what I was asking, so sorry for troubling you.